# Phoenix channel, handle_in call to redirect page?

Tags: controller, phoenix-framework, channel

I have a list of tables page and when a user clicks empty table, it pushes `table:busy` to `TableChannel`. And through `handle_in` call, it creates an order and insert `table_id` in the database.

What I want to ask is that is it possible to redirect page in `handle_in` call?? like in `controller`.

For example, in `controller`, there is a redirect function so when a user creates order, it redirects to `:show` page of order. Is it possible in channel too??

I have tried to use `conn` and `redirect` just like what `controller` has, but it doesnt work.. Is it possible to do it?

Thanks in advance..